# Drupal and View module - Defined fields are displayed only if user is logged in

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, drupal-modules

Working on site development using Drupal. Using View module also.

I did defined severar node's fields I need to show on View layout. My problem is that all those are displayed if visitor logged in, but if he's not logged in, is shows only one node field....

Fields are displayed as html table.

Can you help me how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably enabled the CCK content permissions module, this module allows you to set permissions per field. You can either disable the module or set the appropriate permissions for anonymous users.

It could also be a caching issue (but unlikely), so you should also try to empty all caches (including Views cache under Views-Tools).